# applying the matplotlib draw() freezes window solution to special case

Tags: python, matplotlib

Being new to python, I've come upon the matplotlib draw() freezes window problem myself and found the solution on this site:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import numpy as np
import sys
import Tkinter as tk
import time

def function1(fig, ax):
  ax.cla()
  color_grade_classes = ['#80FF00','#FFFF00','#FF8000', '#FF0000']
  varsi =  random.randint(1, 100)

  for colors, rows  in zip(color_grade_classes, [3,2,1,0] ):  
    indexs = np.arange(5)
    heights = [varsi,varsi/2,varsi/3,0,0]
    ax.bar(indexs, heights, zs = rows,  zdir='y', color=colors, alpha=0.8)
  return fig

class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.wm_title("Embedding in TK")

        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
        self.ax.set_xlabel('X')
        self.ax.set_ylabel('Y')
        self.fig = function1(self.fig, self.ax)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=self.root)
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg( self.canvas, self.root )
        self.toolbar.update()
        self.canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        self.label = tk.Label(text="")
        self.label.pack()
        self.update_clock()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def update_clock(self):
        self.fig = function1(self.fig,self.ax)
        self.canvas.show()
        self.canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        now = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        self.label.configure(text=now)
        self.root.after(1000, self.update_clock)

app=App()
```

My problem is incorporating the following plotting code into it.  It's not quite the same as the example given.  Not sure how to split this up between the function definition and the class declaration.  Can anyone help me on this?

```
t0 = time.time()

while time.time() - t0 <= 10:

    data = np.random.random((32, 32))
    plt.clf()
    im = plt.imshow(data,cmap=cm.gist_gray, interpolation='none')
    plt.ion()
    cbar = plt.colorbar(im)
    cbar.update_normal(im)
    cbar.set_clim(0, np.amax(data))
    plt.draw()

    time.sleep(0.5)


plt.show(block=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

this seems to work.
Basically the `__init__` part initialises the plot and draws the first "frame". Then the function `self.update_clock`is called every 1000ms, and that function calls `function1()` which generates new data and redraws the plot.

I moved things around a bit because of the colorbar in your example, but the idea remains the same.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import random
import numpy as np
import sys
import Tkinter as tk
import time


class App():
def __init__(self):
    self.root = tk.Tk()
    self.root.wm_title("Embedding in TK")

    self.fig = plt.figure()
    self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
    self.ax.set_xlabel('X')
    self.ax.set_ylabel('Y')
    data = np.random.random((32, 32))
    im = self.ax.imshow(data,cmap=cm.gist_gray, interpolation='none')
    self.cbar = self.fig.colorbar(im)
    self.cbar.update_normal(im)
    self.cbar.set_clim(0, np.amax(data))
    self.fig = self.function1(self.fig, self.ax)

    self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=self.root)
    self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg( self.canvas, self.root )
    self.toolbar.update()
    self.canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

    self.label = tk.Label(text="")
    self.label.pack()
    self.update_clock()
    self.root.mainloop()

def update_clock(self):
    self.fig = self.function1(self.fig,self.ax)
    self.canvas.show()
    self.canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
    now = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    self.label.configure(text=now)
    self.root.after(1000, self.update_clock)

def function1(self, fig, ax):
    ax.cla()
    data = np.random.random((32, 32))
    im = ax.imshow(data,cmap=cm.gist_gray, interpolation='none')
    self.cbar.update_normal(im)
    self.cbar.set_clim(0, np.amax(data))
    return fig

app=App()
```

Comment: Nice solution.  If you multiply the random data matrix by a random number, you will notice that the colorbar no longer spans black to white all the time.  Prior code solved this by plt.clf() before each fig update.  Now however self.fig.clf(), nor ax.clf() works.  Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Actually, if I just reverse the order of the cbar lines, my "problem" disappears.  Thanks again!